# How to lazyload library in Angular 4 module?

Tags: javascript, angular, shared-libraries, lazy-loading

I have an app with multiple modules.
One of the modules is to visualize pdf. I use pdf.js which is pretty greedy and the vendor.js is somehow big because of this.

Is there a way to lazyload the library at the same time I lazy load the pdf-module ?

I've noticed this answer, but it doesn't feel as right.
[Load external js script dynamically in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/load-external-js-script-dynamically-in-angular-2)

I am not trying to lazyload a module but an external library.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Nop. I googled. I 've found some answers. Should I describe them ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise this question will get down-voted...

Comment: There's plenty of info out there...

Comment: Could you point them or rephrase my question ? Because I can't find as many answer as you imply

Comment: https://www.google.hr/search?q=Angular+4+Lazy+Loading&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=m9G7WcvEJcvkUuO7tpgH

Comment: I am not talking about lazyloading a component but an external library.

Comment: The article [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) shows you how you can load and compile a module yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you're using Angular CLI.

1. Install `pdfjs-dist` package:

   `npm install pdfjs-dist`
2. Install types for it:

   `npm install @types/pdfjs-dist --save-dev`
3. Add the following import statement **to your lazy loaded module file**:

   `import 'pdfjs-dist';`

The last step will embed pdf.js source code in the lazy loaded bundle when you run `ng build`.

You should be able to access the global PDFJS variable from your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you provide an example or a plunker for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to lazy load external libraries such as `jquery`, `jspdf` you can create some service like:

**lazy-loading-library.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class LazyLoadingLibraryService {
  private loadedLibraries: { [url: string]: ReplaySubject<any> } = {};

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: any) { }

  public loadJs(url: string): Observable<any> {
    if (this.loadedLibraries[url]) {
      return this.loadedLibraries[url].asObservable();
    }

    this.loadedLibraries[url] = new ReplaySubject();

    const script = this.document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = () => {
      this.loadedLibraries[url].next('');
      this.loadedLibraries[url].complete();
    };

    this.document.body.appendChild(script);
    return this.loadedLibraries[url].asObservable();
  }
}
```

And whenever you need some external library just use this service that will load library only once:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private service: LazyLoadingLibraryService) {}

  loadJQuery() {
    this.service.loadJs('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js').subscribe(() => {
        console.log(`jQuery version ${jQuery.fn.jquery} has been loaded`);
    });
  }

  loadJsPdf() {
     this.service.loadJs('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js').subscribe(() => {
      console.log(`JsPdf library has been loaded`);
    });
  }
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DrUuaP9fnUTcv4vpOM2c?p=preview)**

If you're looking for lazy loading angular module then these questions might be helpful for you:

- [How to manually lazy load a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293240/how-to-manually-lazy-load-a-module)
- [How to lazy load Angular 2 components in a TabView (PrimeNG)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171593/how-to-lazy-load-angular-2-components-in-a-tabview-primeng)

Comment: very nice solution mate!